# ASUS Z170-A build won't POST on assembly

Tags: post

I've been trying to help a kid build his first PC, and I'm starting to get a little irritated. a lot of the components he got are overly complicated and complete overkill for the system he's building but heres a basic rundown of the system.

ASUS Z170-A MOBO

Intel i5 6th gen(already verified that cpu and socket match)

Corsair DDR4 8 gig kit(already verified ram is in the proper slots)

some monstrosity dual fan, dual radiator heatsink assembly(non liquid)(already 
verified that thermal paste is properly applied)

Corsair 650W PSU(already ensured that all connectors are in their proper locations and have solid connections)

EVGA Geforce 950 graphics(already tried removing to test onboard graphics)

phantechs case with onboard fan controller card.

I helped him assemble everything but it will not complete a POST. I've tried booting with the ram in various configurations, using the fan controller card and plugging fans directly to the mobo jumpers, with and without the expansion graphics card, no joy. the only LED on the board that lights up is the power LED which stays lit a solid green. when the system powers the fans all spin, except for the fans on the EVGA card which stutter a little like they are trying to start but don't have enough power to keep them spinning. this may be a feature of the low noise configuration because the packaging claims the fans won't spin unless there is a moderate load on the graphics card. I am at a freaking loss here. I've never had this much trouble assembling a custom build before. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can try leaving out the graphics card and only use 1 stick of RAM at a time to narrow things down. Double check that the motherboard supports the specific processor you have, and the type and speed of RAM. If that's all correct it's probably motherboard, RAM, or CPU. Hard to tell which one. Look at the motherboard manual and see if there are any lights or beeps to indicate errors. If the motherboard is supposed to give an error about CPU or RAM issues, and it's not, then maybe it's the motherboard.